# Customize Text Field

Tags: ios, swift3, textfield, xcode8.2

Hi I want to build some thing that look like the picture !

[image: Example Screen Shot]
my problem is that text field can't be two section and use tiny pictures in it just like a picture 
I want to make some thing just like the picture even the green part in the right of the each text field

here is what I want to do

Comment: you can use : textField.rightView = yourCustomView.
you can use UILabel , UIView , UIImageView.. etc for rightView...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a custom view and add it as

```
textField.rightViewMode = .always
    // Set rightview mode
var rightImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "image_icon"))
textField.rightView = rightImageView// Set right view as image view }
```

//textField Its your textfield object , Change it with your own

Try like this

Comment: This question is tagged with Swift not with Objective c, batter if you edit it.

Comment: @NiravD Updated

Comment: one question arabic are right to left correct, in here we need to add `rightView` or `leftView`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik , In ios language it will remain same